# NUXT: why is my prisma entry changed in package.json when running npm build?

Tags: prisma, package.json, nuxtjs3

I want to deploy a Nuxt3 app that uses an API that itself uses prisma.
In my original package.json I have

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "prisma": "^5.7.0",
    ...
}
```

when building the server part with npm build the .output.server dir contains the following package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        ...
        ".prisma": "0.0.0",
        ...
    }
```

Why on earth the prisma entry has changed that way? Can I restore the original entry to install the dependencies on my hosting?